# Retrieve, modify then serve a remote zip archive in Express Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, adm-zip

As you can guess from the title, I am trying to write a small thing just for the sake of learning.

[Here's my code in a Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Dicq2cjf)

As you can see, I am trying to grab a zipped repo from github, according to the express request's parameters, then serve it to the client. Originally I just piped the https response to the client's response, but the zipped archive has a top-level folder (as it comes from github) that I am trying to remove. I'm pretty new to this, and quite lost. Any advice on how do go about modifying the zip archive in memory?

**Edit:** I tried creating a separate archive, then iterating through each of the zipEntries and trying to add it to the new archive, and all of the files do end up on top, like I was aiming for, but they all appear as folders in winrar.

[Here is the second attempt](http://pastebin.com/9pxZjVYE)

Comment: if you fetch, extract, repack and send the zip per response, it will take a lot of time. instead you should serve the file statically.

Comment: I understand that completely, but what I am attempting to do is as stated above. If I don't know how to do it, I would like to know how.